# Иконки для приложения в drawable

Tags: android

Предположим, что я добавил иконки в высоком разрешении для приложения в drawable-hdpi, в остальные директории - ничего. Протестировал приложение на двух смартфонах и одном планшете - везде отображается хорошо, иконки в высоком качестве. Стоит ли добавлять другие разрешения иконок в другие папки, такие, как drawable-mdpi и т.д?

Comment: Только ради соответствующего разрешения иконок

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, что вы протестировали приложение на двух смартфонах и одном планшете -и там всё в порядке.

Только если не предполагать - то их тысячи и десятки тысяч с самими разными dpi и разрешениями экранов.На каком-нибудь, да криво заскейлится.

Answer (score 2):

C таким же успехом Вы могли бы добавить иконки просто в папку drawable.
Для чего создавать -hdpi, если другой альтернативы Вы все равно не даете.

Стоит ли добавлять? Да, стоит, ну либо переходите на svg